# Проблема с запросом к API Vkontakte

Tags: vkontakte-api

Создаю такой запрос к апи вк используя метод friends.areFriends, хочу проверить стаус дружбы с несколькими людьми, для этого использую user_ids.
После чего нужно разделить запятыми айи юзеров, информацию о которых хотим получить. У меня это 1, 2, 6. 1 - это Дуров, 2 - тип какой-то, 6 - брат дурова. Все страницы существуют. Но ответ мне приходит только об одном пользователе, которого мы проверяем первым. Вот ответ: `stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 1 [friend_status] => 0 )`. Раньше вроде всё работало, сейчас не понимаю почему не работает.

В докуметации к методу написано, что нужно user_ids. поставить, и потом перечислять айди через запятаю. всё верно делаю.

```
 $tok = $_SESSION['ob']->access_token;
    $wall = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/friends.areFriends?user_ids=1,2,6&v=5.40&access_token=$tok");
    $wall = json_decode($wall);
    $user = $wall->response[0];
    print_r($user);
```

В чём причина? Подскажите.

Comment: Возможно. Но в коде то всё терпимо? Хотя код убогий, но это тока теста ради пока что.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $user = $wall->response[0];
> ```

Тут вы намеренно берёте только самый первый элемент.

[Этот метод](https://vk.com/dev/friends.areFriends?params[user_ids]=1%2C2%2C4%2C6&params[v]=5.42) возвращает массив объектов, т.е. `$wall->response` – массив со всеми юзерами.

Comment: Ой господи, я не заметил -_- -_- -_-

Comment: $tok = $_SESSION['ob']->access_token;
$wall = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/friends.areFriends?user_ids=".implode(',', $array)."&v=5.40&access_token=$tok");
$wall = json_decode($wall);
$user = $wall->response;

print_r($user);